# Can not get info out of generated QRCode

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am trying to generate QRCode with multiple strings. It is working, however the generated image QRCode is too small inside the `imageView` so it is impossible to read it in(At least I think that is why I can't get info out of it).

This is how it looks:

[image]

And like this I generate it:

```
func generateQRWithInfo(){
    var aggregateData = [String: NSData]()

    if let firstName = firstName?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        aggregateData.updateValue(firstName as NSData, forKey: "firstName")

    }

    if let lastName = lastName?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        aggregateData.updateValue(lastName as NSData, forKey: "lastName")
    }

    if let job = job?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        aggregateData.updateValue(job as NSData, forKey: "job")
    }

    if let organization = organization?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        aggregateData.updateValue(organization as NSData, forKey: "organization")
    }

    if let mobilePhone = mobilePhone?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        aggregateData.updateValue(mobilePhone as NSData, forKey: "mobilePhone")
    }

    if let workPhone = workPhone?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        aggregateData.updateValue(workPhone as NSData, forKey: "workPhone")
    }

    if let email = email?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        aggregateData.updateValue(email as NSData, forKey: "email")
    }

    let archived = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: aggregateData)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")

    filter?.setValue(archived, forKey: "inputMessage")
    filter?.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

    let qrCodeImage = filter?.outputImage
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    //let cgImage = context.createCGImage(qrCodeImage!, from: (qrCodeImage?.extent)!)

    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 50,y: 50)

    let output = filter?.outputImage?.applying(transform)

    let newImage = UIImage(ciImage: output!)

    qrImageView.image = newImage
}
```

I do not know if it is how it should be but I can't get info out of it. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it because you have too much information in the QR code? Try removing a few attributes and see if it is readable.

Comment: @Jordan I tried that. It is still same.

Comment: So you need the dimensions of the code to be larger - instead of 30x30, you need it 500x500?

Comment: Hmm.. I do not know anymore.. I got it reading but I can't get information out of it anymore. I think I am generating it wrong with multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR Codes holds lots of data based on these parameters.

- Data type
- Size a.k.a pixels
- Error correction level

Data type can be Numeric, Alphanumeric and Binary.
Error correction level can be categorised as Type L,M,Q and H based on loss recovery possible.

so as per your case you want to generate 30*30 alphanumeric so obviously you cant store more then allowed values. So make it bigger or reduce the data. To make a note all the QR code readers are not same.

For more info check this [table](http://blog.qr4.nl/page/QR-Code-Data-Capacity.aspx)